# cannot install Imager::File::PNG with cpan in windows 10

Tags: perl, cpan, libpng

I need to install WWW::Mechanize::Chrome and the only dependency left to install is Imager::File::PNG.
I'm not able to install Imager::File::PNG. I have downloaded [libpng](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/latest/download). But don't know how to compile it into lib files and proceed to install Imager::File:PNG. Does anyone have the lib for libpng or help me out how to make it.

```
>  cpan Imager::File::PNG                                                                                               
Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4
CPAN: Term::ANSIColor loaded ok (v4.02)
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.45)
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 26 Jun 2020 05:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Imager::File::PNG'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.85)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.063)
Checksum for C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TO\TONYC\Imager-File-PNG-0.95.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.96)
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/META.yml
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/README
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/impng.h
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/MANIFEST
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/impng.c
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/PNG.xs
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/t/
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/t/00load.t
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/t/10png.t
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/Changes
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/Makefile.PL
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/MANIFEST.SKIP
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/PNG.pm
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/cover.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/rgb16.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/cover16.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/bipalette.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/coveri.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/coverpal.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/coverpali.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/bilevel.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/gray.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/graya.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/paltrans.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/cover16i.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/palette.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/comment.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/rgb8.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/pal.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/rgb8i.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/palette_out.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/testimg/badcrc.png
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/META.json
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/inc/
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/inc/Devel/
Imager-File-PNG-0.95/inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.62)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4417)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150005)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v3.03)
Configuring T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.95.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4
PNG: building independently
PNG: Generic: includes found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.6: includes found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.5: includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.4: includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.2: includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.0: includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: base (+libz): includes found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.6 (+libz): includes found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.5 (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.4 (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.2 (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: v1.0 (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: Checking if the compiler can find them on its own
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lkernel32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -luser32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lgdi32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwinspool
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcomdlg32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -ladvapi32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lshell32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lole32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -loleaut32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lnetapi32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -luuid
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lws2_32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lmpr
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwinmm
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lversion
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lodbc32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lodbccp32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcomctl32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lmsvcrt
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png.h', 'stdio.h', 'png'
OS unsupported: PNG libraries or headers not found
Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
  TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.95.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Cygwin?

Comment: not really. But if there is some possibility to install the library with that, I'll install it

Comment: I just tried to install it without Cygwin using Strawberry Perl version 5.30 and it installed fine here. I cannot remember that I have installed libpng, but I got the message `PNG: found via pkg-config libpng`..

Comment: Anyways , could u help me out how to use Cygwin, inorder to install libpng?

Comment: I think `libpng.a` comes with Strawberry Perl. I found the file here: `C:\Strawberry\c\libpng.a`. Can you try Strawberry Perl first?

Comment: ok ,I will try. And one more thing... if I get that library file, can I copy it in another system and run without installing Strawberry Perl

Comment: Maybe.. it depends. Another possibility is to use [PAR::Packer](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) it can include the library file directly in an .exe file

Comment: According to [the release notes](http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.30.2.1-64bit.html) libpng-1.6.37 is included in Strawberry Perl 5.30.2

Comment: ok dude. I'll check. BTW thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to install Imager::File::PNG with straberry Perl Cpan client.But it failed to install it.The error is -Failed during this command:
 TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.95.tar.gz            : make NO

Comment: Can we continue the discussion on email? You can find my email address in my profile..

Comment: ok sure........